# Custom bst book entry no editors

Tags: natbib, custom-bib

I've created a custom .bst file and it does not show the editors correctly.

**My current .bst entry for book is as follow:**

```
FUNCTION {book}
{ output.bibitem
  author empty$
    { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
      editor format.key output
    }
    { format.authors output.nonnull
      crossref missing$
        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
        'skip$
      if$
    }
  if$
  format.date "year" output.check
  date.block
  format.btitle "title" output.check
  crossref missing$
    { format.bvolume output
      new.block
      format.number.series output
      format.edition output
      new.sentence
      format.publisher.address output
    }
    {
      new.block
      format.book.crossref output.nonnull
    }
  if$
  format.isbn output
  new.block
  format.note output
  fin.entry
  write.url
}
```

The entry I receive for the following bib entry is:

```
@Book{brink2016real,
  title         = {Real-world machine learning},
  publisher     = {Manning Publications Company},
  year          = {2016},
  author        = {Brink, Henrik and Richards, Joseph and Fetherolf, Mark},
  editor        = {Kline, Susanna and Scherer, Al and Booth, Olivia and Harlovic, Ozren},
  address       = {Greenwich, USA},
  __markedentry = {[Hp i7:1]},
  keywords      = {rank5},
}
```

In my references it doesn't display the editors at all. Why would that be happening?

> Brink, H., Richards, J. and Fetherolf, M. 2016. *Real-world machine*
>   *learning*. Greenwich, USA: Manning Publications Company.

**This could be a MWP:**

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article} 
\pagestyle{plain}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst,semicolon]{usbib}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Reference List}
\bibliographystyle{CUSTOM.bst}
\begin{document}
\section*{CUSTOM}
In this section we reference the books \citet{brink2016real}.


\bibliography{Thesisbib.bib}

\end{document}
```

With the editors displaying I'd like them to show as follow:

> Brink, H., Richards, J. and Fetherolf, M. 2016. *Real-world machine*
>   *learning*. Horn, K. and Manning, F. (eds). Greenwich, USA: Manning Publications Company.

Comment: It would be easier to investigate your problem if you would include a minimal but working bst showing your problem. Right now we can not reproduce the problem without completing the bst.

Comment: Where and how would you like to see the editors displayed? Would it be possible to upload the entire `CUSTOM.bst` to a plain-text sharing website such as pastebing, Gitlab snippets or GitHub Gists, that would make it easier for me to test a possible solution. This may be just an example, but in case of this specific book I don't think you need to list the editors. The authors will do just fine. Note that the editors are neither listed on the cover nor on the title page, they can only be found on the verso of the title page.

Comment: Please find attached, I've uploaded the CUSTOM.bst. (https://pastebin.com/HxwbPtjT) I need to show the editors for each book if any as per my university's requirements.

Comment: As to why there are no editors displayed by your `CUSTOM.bst`: The `format.editors` part of you code is in a conditional block which is only called when `author empty$` is true, so when there are no authors. Like moewe wrote this is typical behaviour in the bibliography.

Comment: Usually you can restrict yourself to the people named on the cover or on the title page. For `@book` you usually need an `author`, but `editor`s are optional and usually only given if their contribution is significant (for example when we talk about the edition of an ancient work, or the collected works of someone ...). `@incollection`s will have both `editor`s (of the enclosing `@collection`) and `author`s (of the particular chapter/paper).

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I'm going to have a chat with my promoter about this.

Comment: Where would you have to show them? It would probably not make sense to list them before the title (as there could be confusion between authors and editors in that case), so they would be listed after the title (`biblatex` does that), but *how* should they be listed. Can you add an example of the expected output, please?

Comment: Thank you very much for the assistance. I've added an example. Right after teh title with (eds).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by [Marcel Krüger](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/80496/marcel-kr%c3%bcger) in the comments at the moment your style can only print either the `author` or the `editor` field, where `author`s are preferred.

We can slightly modify the file so that the `editor`s are printed after the title if the `author` field is present. Note that I also moved a few definitions around since they were not defined before they were used in some situation which leads to errors. The necessary diff is

```
--- CUSTOM-orig.bst 2018-08-23 14:50:16.153874000 +0200
+++ CUSTOM.bst  2018-08-23 14:53:31.858917200 +0200
@@ -1,5 +1,5 @@
 %%
-%% This is file `ussagus.bst',
+%% This is file `CUSTOM.bst',
 %% generated with the docstrip utility.
 %%
 %% The original source files were:
@@ -79,7 +79,7 @@
     url
     volume
     year
-   doi
+    doi
   }
   {}
   { label extra.label sort.label short.list }
@@ -130,27 +130,6 @@
   newline$
 }

-FUNCTION {write.doi}
-{ doi empty$
-    { "" }
-   { new.block "doi:" doi * "" * }
-  if$ 
-}
-
-FUNCTION {write.dois}
-{ doi empty$ 'skip$
-    { swap$ empty$
-        {pop$ doi}
-        {
-          new.block ". doi:" doi * "" * 
-          %swap$
-          n.dashify
-          *
-        }
-      if$
-    }
-  if$
-}

 FUNCTION {new.block}
 { output.state before.all =
@@ -1101,6 +1080,29 @@
 { organization "organization" bibinfo.check format.org.or.pub
 }

+FUNCTION {write.doi}
+{ doi empty$
+    { "" }
+    { new.block "doi:" doi * "" * }
+  if$ 
+}
+
+FUNCTION {write.dois}
+{ doi empty$ 'skip$
+    { swap$ empty$
+        {pop$ doi}
+        {
+          new.block ". doi:" doi * "" * 
+          %swap$
+          n.dashify
+          *
+        }
+      if$
+    }
+  if$
+}
+
+
 FUNCTION {article}
 { output.bibitem
   format.authors "author" output.check
@@ -1133,12 +1135,7 @@
     { format.editors "author and editor" output.check
       editor format.key output
     }
-    { format.authors output.nonnull
-      crossref missing$
-        { "author and editor" editor either.or.check }
-        'skip$
-      if$
-    }
+    { format.authors output.nonnull }
   if$
   format.date "year" output.check
   date.block
@@ -1146,6 +1143,11 @@
   crossref missing$
     { format.bvolume output
       new.block
+      author empty$
+        'skip$
+        { format.editors output }
+      if$
+      new.block
       format.number.series output
       format.edition output
       new.sentence
@@ -1266,15 +1268,13 @@
         { format.organization.address output }
         { organization "organization" bibinfo.check output
           format.publisher.address output
-         format.proceeds.pages output  
-         write.dois output
+          format.proceeds.pages output  
+          write.dois output
         }
-       
       if$
       format.isbn output
       format.issn output
     }
-   
     { format.incoll.inproc.crossref output.nonnull
       format.proceeds.pages output
     }
```

and you can find the modified version along with the "change history" at https://gist.github.com/moewew/cb8da22cda4fb12d38572130cf46ce9d.

With the new `CUSTOM.bst` the MWE

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[longnamesfirst,semicolon]{usbib}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\renewcommand{\bibname}{Reference List}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@Book{brink2016real,
  title         = {Real-world machine learning},
  publisher     = {Manning Publications Company},
  year          = {2016},
  author        = {Brink, Henrik and Richards, Joseph and Fetherolf, Mark},
  editor        = {Kline, Susanna and Scherer, Al and Booth, Olivia and Harlovic, Ozren},
  address       = {Greenwich, USA},
}
\end{filecontents}

\begin{document}
In this section we reference the books \citet{brink2016real}.

\bibliographystyle{CUSTOM}
\bibliography{\jobname}
\end{document}
```

gives

> Brink, H., Richards, J. and Fetherolf, M. 2016. *Real-world machine learning*. Kline, S., Scherer, A., Booth, O. and Harlovic, O. (eds.). Greenwich, USA: Manning Publications Company.

Note that in this particular case I don't think the editors need to be shown. The editors are not listed on the cover or the title page of the book. They can only be found on the verso of the title page along with other people involved in publishing that book.

Usually editors for `@book` entries are only included if their contribution is significant to the work (e.g. editors of ancient works or compilers of collected works). `editor`s of `@collection`s and in `@incollection`s are different, they are usually required since they are the primary creator of the (corresponding) `@collection`.